# Magento(1.9.1.1):Email and name not saved

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm having an issue with customer email and name not being saved in order details. It happens often. sometime this issue is not occuring.

The customer's email, account ID, first name and last name are not being written to the table sales_flat_order Also table sales_flat_order_grid the customer ID missing.
[image]

This issue also described here : https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-1-x-Technical-Issues/missing-data-in-sales-orders/td-p/26958

Comment: have you done any customization ?

Comment: no, i have did not apply any customization.

Comment: try debugging, and try to reproduce the same error and check the log file

Comment: Your welcome...

Comment: Same problem here with Magento 1.9.4.0 and Amasty One Step Checkout (latest build) when a guest do an order.

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Comment: sorry I did not found any solution for this